# Java enum used in Tetris game: strange behavior

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, collections, enums

Using NetBeans IDE 8.2, I've been building a rudimentary Java Tetris game with an enum representing the Tetromino shapes. The game has a main board/grid with the active piece. It also contains a preview grid to show the next piece that will appear. I use an ArrayList and Collections.shuffle to permutate through the shapes so that the player is certain to get a desired shape in that particular "bag" of seven shapes.

Once the active piece has landed, a method call is made to choose a new piece (see code snippet).

I am able to get through the first seven pieces without issue. Once a piece has landed, the next piece appears in the proper place. However, once I have gotten through the first bag and a second set of pieces is generated, the "active" piece no longer appears and the preview piece starts jumping vertically up and down on the screen. It's as if a reference can no longer determine which is the active piece and which is the next (preview) piece. I think it's no coincidence that the problem only occurs when a piece has come up for a second time.

Here are some code snippets of the enum and the method that chooses the next piece. The "resetPos()" method in the enum is there to reset its relative position so that it spawns from the correct place on the board. Can you see where I've gone wrong? Thank you very much for your help!

```
enum Tetrominoes {
    SBlock(new Point[]{new Point(-1,0), new Point(0,0), new Point(-2,1),
        new Point(-1,1)}),
    ZBlock(new Point[]{new Point(-2,0), new Point(-1,0), new Point(-1,1),
        new Point(0,1)}),
    JBlock(new Point[]{new Point(-2,0), new Point(-2,1), new Point(-1,1),
        new Point(0,1)}),
    LBlock(new Point[]{new Point(0,0), new Point(-2,1), new Point(-1,1),
        new Point(0,1)}),
    OBlock(new Point[]{new Point(-1,0), new Point(0,0), new Point(-1,1),
        new Point(0,1)}),
    TBlock(new Point[]{new Point(-1,0), new Point(-2,1), new Point(-1,1),
        new Point(0,1)}),
    IBlock(new Point[]{new Point(-2,0), new Point(-1,0), new Point(0,0),
        new Point(1,0)});

    final Point[] relativeStartPos;
    Point[] relativeCurrPos;

    private Tetrominoes(Point[] relativeStartPos) {
        this.relativeStartPos = relativeStartPos;
        relativeCurrPos = new Point[4];
        resetPos();
    }

    void resetPos() {
        relativeCurrPos = relativeStartPos.clone();
    }

    void down() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            (relativeCurrPos[i].y)++;
        }
    }
}
```

//******

```
// ArrayList declaration appearing earlier in code
private ArrayList<Integer> randBag = new ArrayList<Integer>();

void selectBlock() {
    Tetrominoes[] tetro = Tetrominoes.values();
    if(randBag.isEmpty()) {
        Collections.addAll(randBag, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        Collections.shuffle(randBag);
    }
    currentBlock = tetro[nextBlock.ordinal()];
    currentBlock.resetPos();

    randBag.remove(0);
    if(randBag.isEmpty()) {
        Collections.addAll(randBag, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        Collections.shuffle(randBag);
    }              
    nextBlock = tetro[randBag.get(0)];
    nextBlock.resetPos();
}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: you should use a class, not an enum. Enum are supposed to be constant but your enum positons change

Comment: I'm with @jhamon as this seems a corruption of what an enum should be.

Comment: You have 7 enum values. There will only ever be exactly 7. A Tetris game will have a lot more than 7 pieces on the board, so you can't use the 7 enum values to represent all pieces on the board. The enum values can represent the *shape* of a piece, but the rotation and position must be kept elsewhere. As already mentioned, the enums should be immutable.

Comment: Enums contain *fixed* set of values so using enum as piece means your game should use only seven pieces, while what you probably meant is to use enum as representation of *type* of piece. So it should be more like `enum PieceType{..types here..}` `class Piece{ EnumType type, int xPosition, int yPosition, int rotation, ...constructors/getters/other}`.

Comment: to explain your issue: each type of piece is unique. When you create a "new" piece of an existing type, you juste get all the existing piece of this type and reset its coordinates

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone, I've been primarily a C++ programmer in the past and I misunderstood this newfangled Java enum. I changed the enum into a class with the Points as a 2D array. I was able to solve the problem relatively quickly.